# Form level visited prop

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-redux-form

I have multiple forms and I want to know which one of them was visited.

`visited` or `touched` don't help because they're about fields, and forcing the user to click one of the fields just for that isn't what I want nor is intuitive.

So is there another way to know if a form was visited?

I'm on redux-form 6.8.0.

Comment: Why not wrap every form on its individual component and watch `componentDidMount` events?